# Draw table according to user provided width and height

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new with VBA in Excel. What I want to accomplish is this. When a user enters a length of say 5, then 5 columns must be outlined red. Then also when a user enters a width of say 6, then 6 rows must be outlined red. Example:

[image]

[image]

I have this code thus far:

**On worksheet change:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If (Target.Address = "$A$2") Then
    Call Draw2DTankl
  ElseIf (Target.Address = "$B$2") Then
    Call Draw2DTankw
  End If
End Sub
```

**Draw2DTankl:**

```
Sub Draw2DTankl()

  On Error Resume Next
  Cells(2, 4).Value = ""
  Dim x As Range
  Set x = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells

  x.Borders.LineStyle = xNone

  Range("A1") = "Length"


  Dim Length As Integer


   Length = CInt(Cells(2, 1).Value)


   If (Length > 30) Then
    MsgBox "A length of a maximum 30 is allowed"
    Exit Sub
  End If
  If (Length < 0) Then
    MsgBox "Invalid length value entered"
    Exit Sub
  End If


   Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range, r As Range
    If (Length > 0) Then
    Rws = 20
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(20, "H"), Cells(Rws, 8 + Length - 1))

    For Each r In Rng.Cells

            With r.Borders

                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Weight = xlMedium
                .ColorIndex = 3

            End With
    Next r
    End If

If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
    MsgBox Err.Description
End If

End Sub
```

**Draw2DTankw:**

```
Sub Draw2DTankw()

  On Error Resume Next
  Cells(2, 4).Value = ""
  Dim x As Range
  Set x = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells

  x.Borders.LineStyle = xNone


  Range("B1") = "Width"


  Dim Width As Integer



   Width = CInt(Cells(2, 2).Value)


  If (Width > 30) Then
    MsgBox "A width of a maximum 30 is allowed"
    Exit Sub
  End If
  If (Width < 0) Then
    MsgBox "Invalid Width value entered"
    Exit Sub
  End If


     Dim Col As Long, Rng As Range, r As Range
    If (Width > 0) Then
    Col = 21
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(21, "H"), Cells(Col, 8 + Length - 1))

    For Each r In Rng.Cells

            With r.Borders

                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Weight = xlMedium
                .ColorIndex = 3

            End With
    Next r
    End If

If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
    MsgBox Err.Description
End If

End Sub
```

Please help me. My code doesn't work. The length works, but that brakes when I change the width.

**Entering my length draws:**

[image]

Which is correct. But then if I enter the width of 6 this happens: (my length also dissapears)

[image]

**I apologize for this long post!**

Comment: After you draw the length, you are erasing and redrawing when you call the sub drawing the width. Since the length is explicitly specified as 2 in your width drawing sub, you will draw your tank 2 units long. You should combine the subs into one that draws both length and width if either cell is changed, like Jonathan's answer below. Also, good work on formatting and structuring your question. You've obviously put in some effort in developing your solution.

Comment: I see what you mean! Thanks! I will definitely look into this. Also, thanks for the compliment about the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like in the Draw2DTankw you have Width declared above but in the rng you are using length

> Dim Width As Integer  Width = CInt(Cells(2, 2).Value)
>
> Set Rng = Range(Cells(21, "H"), Cells(Col, 8 + Length - 1))

I've modified your code to draw both height and width by extending the range to include the width.  This worked with I test it.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If (Target.Address = "$A$2") Or (Target.Address = "$B$2") Then
  DrawTable
  End If
End Sub

Sub DrawTable()

  On Error Resume Next
  Cells(2, 4).Value = ""
  Dim x As Range
  Set x = ActiveSheet.Cells

  x.Borders.LineStyle = xNone

  Range("A1") = "Length"


  Dim Length As Integer
   Length = CInt(Cells(2, 1).Value)
   'Combined Width sections
  Dim Width As Integer
   Width = CInt(Cells(2, 2).Value)

   If (Length > 30) Then
    MsgBox "A length of a maximum 30 is allowed"
    Exit Sub
    ElseIf (Width > 30) Then
    MsgBox "A width of a maximum 30 is allowed"
    Exit Sub
    ElseIf (Length < 0) Then
    MsgBox "Invalid length value entered"
    Exit Sub
    ElseIf (Width < 0) Then
    MsgBox "Invalid Width value entered"
    Exit Sub
  End If


   Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range, r As Range
    If (Length > 0) Then
    Rws = 20
    'Added width to cells(rws)
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(20, "H"), Cells(Rws + Width - 1, 8 + Length - 1))

    For Each r In Rng.Cells

            With r.Borders

                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Weight = xlMedium
                .ColorIndex = 3

            End With
    Next r
    End If

If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
    MsgBox Err.Description
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this then.